# Angular child ng-click event does not fire after parent ng-click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pug, mean

I am pretty new to Angular so I have not figured out all its little quirks yet. Currently I have button that opens an overlay with ng-click="open()". Inside the overlay there is another button that closes the overlay with ng-click="close()".

As it stands now the ng-click events will not fire if the other is present with in the view. If ng-click="open()" is present, ng-click="close()" will not fire and vice versa.

Here is a simpler version of what I am talking about, as what I am working on is a little hefty on the actual app:

**View**

```
<button ng-click="open()">Open</button>

<div id="overlay">
   <button ng-click="close()">Close</button>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.open = function(){
   //some move.js to open the overlay
}

$scope.close = function(){
   //some move.js to close the overlay
}
```

The overlay is not generated dynamically and is rendered to the page onload.

Here is the solution as provided by @sz tech below. Not the $compile method. http://codepen.io/NicholasByDesign/pen/WwqMXa?editors=1010

Just kind of side note, as I do not think it will make a difference. I am working within a nodejs and jade environment. I put it as regular HTML and left out the controller code wrapping the open/close functions to simplify things.

Comment: Can you reproduce simple demo?

Comment: By overlay, you are referring to the modal box that opens? If that's the case then when overlay is displayed, the controls behind it are locked.

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I have updated my answer with a simple demo on what I mean.

Comment: @Dev-One Thanks for the heads up, Yes it is a modal,  In this case then can you direct me to a typical Angular approach on what other people are doing to handle close events?

Comment: Would it be possible to use ng-modal in your code? I really find this blog interesting when creating modals: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-angularjs-modal-service

Comment: This seems to have something to do with editing the `div.innerHTML` where the close button is - I made it change the innerHTML of a different div and it works. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGqRma?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are updating (`div.innerHTML += "close";`) the div which contains the angular code (`ng-click="close()"`) and the binding will disappear, try to recompile the div after the update and it will work. Try out this code:

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope,$compile) {
   var div = document.getElementById('div');

   $scope.open = function(){
     div.innerHTML += "open";
         $compile(div)($scope);
   }

   $scope.close = function(){
     div.innerHTML += "close";
         $compile(div)($scope);
   }
});
```

As you can see I'm recompiling the `div` and bind the current scope to it, and it will work. Here's the working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNrRKL?editors=1010

Comment: Yep, that did it! I did see the $compile method in another example, but that one was far more extravagant so I did not think it applied to my use case. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
   var div = angular.element(document.getElementById('div'));

   $scope.open = function(){
       div.append("open");
   }

   $scope.close = function(){
       div.append("close");
   }
});
```

Comment: So that does work, however the link to the codepen was a demo of the issue at hand. I still would be able to understand why events do not work at times and what an angular solution would be.

Comment: Maybe angularjs can‘t blended native js